# Conditional output dependent on --shell-escape option value

Tags: conditionals, latexmk, shell-escape

I would like to print the git revision of the document with the *latexgit* package, which requires the `--shell-escape` option to work.

As this feature is very optional for building the document, I would like to make loading the package and printing the version dependent of the presence of the `--shell-escape` switch, so the document could be build with or without the switch without failure.

How could I do that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexgit}
\begin{document} 

Git: \#\gitcommithash

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pdftex` maintains a `\pdfshellescape` read-only integer variable which can have three values

- 0 if the engine is called with `-no-shell-escape`
- 1 if the engine is called with `-shell-escape`
- 2 otherwise (meaning that the restricted shell escape is available)

You can make it engine independent by loading `pdftexcmds`:

```
\usepackage{pdftexcmds} % \RequirePackage in a .sty file
\makeatletter % if not in a .sty file
\ifcase\numexpr\pdf@shellescape\relax
   <code for -no-shell-escape>%
\or
   <code for -shell-escape>%
\or
   <code for the standard>%
\fi
\makeatother
```

Quite likely, the codes for 0 and 2 will be the same, so a different strategy could be

```
\usepackage{pdftexcmds} % \RequirePackage in a .sty file
\makeatletter % if not in a .sty file
\ifnum\pdf@shellescape=1
   <code for -shell-escape>%
\else
   <code for no option>%
\fi
\makeatother
```

A wrapper around this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doifshellescape}{%
  \ifnum\pdf@shellescape=1
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\doifshellescape{YES}{NO}

\end{document}
```

The macro `\doifshellescape` will use `YES` if the shell escape is active, `NO` otherwise.

With `expl3` we just have to make a user-level alias; better yet, we have three possibilities

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \shellescapeTF \sys_if_shell_unrestricted:TF
\cs_set_eq:NN \shellescapeF \sys_if_shell_unrestricted:F
\cs_set_eq:NN \shellescapeT \sys_if_shell_unrestricted:T
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\shellescapeTF{YES}{NO}
\shellescapeT{YES}
\shellescapeF{NO}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick help! This works fine in my MWE! However my environment seems to be more complex than i though. It doesn't work there (a TIKZ node in a template for a Beamer title page. I'll try to make up an MWE and come back).

Comment: @hoeni I added a wrapper around the idea.

Comment: Wow that works like a charm. Now it will take me some time to learn and understand what I'm doing here :-) Two questions at moment: First: Why did the code not work inside my TIKZ node until you wrapped it in a command? Second: That expl3 thing from the last solution, do I understand this correct as some kind of "write-code-for-the-next-LaTeX-in the-current-Latex-wrapper?

Comment: @hoeni TikZ does several changes to cope with its requirements, so it's difficult to say without an example. Yes, `expl3` is the programming layer on which LaTeX3 will be built upon.